Solving partial differential equations using MacCormack scheme and to quantify in what situations this scheme is stable using von Neumann stability
I am trying to simulate Alfven waves and for that, I need to solve partial differential equations using the MacCormack scheme.
The predictor steps are:
\begin{align}
u^p_j&=u_j^n-c\left(b_{j+1}^n-b_j^n\right) \\
b^p_j&=b_j^n-c\left(u_{j+1}^n-u_j^n\right)
\end{align}
and the correction step equations are:
\begin{align}
u^{n+1}_j&=\frac{1}{2}\left[u_j^n+u_j^p-c\left(b_{j}^p-b_{j-1}^p\right)\right] \\
b^{n+1}_j&=\frac{1}{2}\left[b_j^n+b_j^p-c\left(u_{j}^p-u_{j-1}^p\right)\right]
\end{align}
Also $c=c_A(\Delta t/\Delta z)$ with $\Delta t$ as the time-step and $\Delta x$ as the step between two grid points.
The eigenmodes of the equations are of the form
$$u_j^n=\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}\Delta z$$
where $k$ is a real spatial wave number, $\xi$ is complex and $i$ is the complex unit. The system is unstable for $|\xi| > 1$.
How do I use the expressions for the two steps and the eigenmodes, find, in terms of $c$, the condition for which the system is stable?
This is the first time I am doing this, any detailed explanation of the derivation would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I substituted the value of the eigenmodes into the predictor step and following that I substituted the predictor step into the correction step.

After that I divided the whole expression through $$u_j^n=\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}\Delta z$$

If there are any mistakes till this point please correct me, and how do I get the terms in order so I could use the sin and cosine expressions.
And how do I proceed further with the problem?
Thank You!

Don't use images/screenshots for text and math or equations. Use MathJax instead.

You're looking to perform von Neumann stability analysis on the PDE. Essentially you will replace the variables of your PDE with your trial function with accounting for the increments in space/time indices as follows:
\begin{align}
u_j^n&=\xi^n\exp\left(ikj\right) \\
u_{j+1}^n&=\xi^n\exp\left(ik(j+1)\right) \\
u_{j-1}^n&=\xi^n\exp\left(ik(j-1)\right) \\
u_{j}^{n+1}&=\xi^{n+1}\exp\left(ikj\right)
\end{align}
(though I think it's more common, when dealing with a two-variable system, to see a constant in front to indicate which term you're dealing with; i.e. $u_j^n=U\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}$ and $b_j^n=B\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}$). As an example, for the first term of the predictor, you should get something like,
\begin{align}
u^p_j&=U\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}-c\left(B\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ik(j+1)}-B\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}\right)\\
&=\left[U-cB\left(\mathrm{e}^{ik}-1\right)\right]\xi^n\mathrm{e}^{ikj}
\end{align}
and similarly for the second term. Both of these would end up in the corrector step (it might also be easier to push both predictor terms into corrector step & solve from there, but YMMV).
After plugging in these into the PDE, it's just a matter of dividing through like terms and using relations like $\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)=2i\sin(x)$ (and probably the cosine form also) to reduce it down to an eigenvalue equation,
\begin{align}
  \xi U&=f_1(c, k,\,\Delta t,\,\Delta x)\cdot U+f_2(c, k,\,\Delta t,\,\Delta x)\cdot B \\
  \xi B&=f_3(c, k,\,\Delta t,\,\Delta x)\cdot U+f_4(c, k,\,\Delta t,\,\Delta x)\cdot B,
\end{align}
that can be solved for $\xi$ in terms of the remaining constants of the PDE. The stability is then determined by the condition you've given in the post $\vert\xi\vert\leq1$ (i.e., the growth factor must be less than one).

I have substituted the predictor step into the correction step, I have added those pics in the edit. Could you advise how to move forward?

@subrojitroy no, that would violate the homework-like problems policy on the site. At this point in the problem, it's just a matter of multiplying and dividing.

That said, your trial function should be as I wrote it: $u_j^n=U\xi^n\exp(ikj)$ (i.e., without the $\Delta z$ in it). Try it that way.
